# maven repository for EMR hadoop

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

Does AWS EMR has its own maven repository for EMR Hadoop/Spark/Others similar to that of

1. HDP [ http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/ ]
2. CDH [ https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos ]

Questions:

- If so, what is the URL of it?
- If thats not the case, what would the community recommend to build a spark jar to be executed on an EMR instance?

Answer (score 7):

Good news, a maven repository for EMR dependencies (including Amazon's hadoop version) is now available!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-artifact-repository.html

Comment: But it only contains hadoop and hive artifacts..

eg: aws s3 ls s3://eu-central-1-emr-artifacts/emr-6.5.0/repos/maven/org/apache/

Answer (score 1):

No, currently EMR do not have its Hadoop distributions open to public.

Answer (score -1):

I also couldn't find a official Maven Repository with the patched Hadoop code from AWS. But as long as I understood are the patches that aws applied not necessary for local usage.

What i recommend is to use the official apache hadoop repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop with the same version that emr uses in their environment.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop.html